# Differences between sums of reciprocals of primes and products thereof.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

I am not a number theorist, but I know that number theorists are notorious for estimating sums including primes. So, I have the following question, which I may not have seen addressed, but I am sure has been thought of by others before.

Is it true that the difference
$$\sum_{p\leq N} 1/p \ - \sum_{ p<q \leq N} 1/(p\cdot q) $$
has a positive lower bound as $N$ increases? What about
$$\sum_{ p<q \leq N} 1/p\cdot q\ - \sum_{ p<q<r \leq N} 1/(p\cdot q \cdot r)?$$

Or what about sligt variations like
$$\sum_{p\leq N} 1/p \ - 2\sum_{p<q \leq N} 1/(p\cdot q) $$
and
$$\sum_{2\leq p<q \leq N} 1/p\cdot q\ - 2\sum_{p<q<r \leq N} 1/(p\cdot q \cdot r)?$$

In all the above cases, $p,q$ and $r$ denote prime numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\sum_{p < q \leq N}{\frac{1}{pq}} = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_{p \leq N}{\frac{1}{p}}\right)^2-\sum_{p \leq N}{\frac{1}{p^2}}\right],$$

and since $\sum_p{\frac{1}{p}}=\infty$ and $\sum_{p}{\frac{1}{p^2}} < \infty$,

it follows that $\sum_{p < q \leq N}{\frac{1}{pq}} -\sum_{p \leq N}{\frac{1}{p}} \rightarrow \infty$.

In fact, the second sum is negligible compared to the first one.

Similarly, $$\left(\sum_{p \leq N}{\frac{1}{p}}\right)^3=6\sum_{p <q<r \leq N}{\frac{1}{pqr}}+3\sum_{p < q \leq N}{\left(\frac{1}{p^2q}+\frac{1}{pq^2}\right)}+\sum_{p \leq N}{\frac{1}{p^3}},$$

so that $\sum_{p< q \leq N}{\frac{1}{pq}}$ is negligible compared to $\sum_{p < q< r}{\frac{1}{pqr}}$.